# Generalized Solution to DIfferential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $x'=\sqrt{|x|}, x(0)=0$ the solution is $x=0,x=\frac{1}{4}t^2 sign(t)$.

I'm supposed to generalize the solution and show that this inital-value problem has a two-parameter family of solutions. I remember generalizing solutions in my first ODE class based on the solutions, but this problem seems to want me to express a solution such

$x=x(t; \mu,x_0,t_0)$ where $x_0=x_0(\mu), t_0=t_0(\mu)$

I am a little confused on how to go about this with an introduction of $\mu$ that defines initial values and whatnot (I assume this is getting rid of the reliance on the intial values or something). Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The two-parameter family you want is for a single initial-value problem, not for the set of initial-value problems indexed by $x_0, t_0$.  The appearance of $x=x(t; \mu,x_0,t_0)$ is only a distraction here: for you $x_0=0$ and $t_0=0$ are rigidly fixed.

What you were expected to do was to define
$$x(t;a,b) = \begin{cases} 0,\quad & a\le t\le b \\ (t-b)^2/4,\quad & t>b \\ -(t-a)^2/4,\quad & t<a \end{cases} $$ 
where $a\le 0$ and $b\ge 0$ are two parameters. All of the above are solutions of the IVP with $x(0)=0$.